# Wayland Keyboard Shortcuts for Window management not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, wayland

Newly bound Keyboard shortcuts to a special key (labeled 'Front' on my old Sun keyboard) are not working for Window management on my system. I was able to map that key in Ubuntu 18.04 with X.org however.

I am now running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with Wayland.
If I go into Settings/Keyboard/Keyboard Shortcuts/Windows, and click on "Raise window if covered, otherwise lower it", and then press that 'Front' key on my keyboard to bind it, it shows 0x10 as the binding. However, subsequently pressing that key has no effect.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround?